# How to draw TabControl in the following shape in c# Winform?

Tags: c#, winforms

[image: TabControl Cut from Corner]

How to draw TabControl in the following shape in c# Winform?

I have tried this Code in TabControl Paint.

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        using (var p = new GraphicsPath())
        {
            p.AddPolygon(new Point[] {
            new Point(this.Width, 0), 
            new Point(0, 0),
            new Point(0, Height), 
            new Point(Width - 5, Height),
            new Point(Width, Height -5)
            });

            this.Region = new Region(p);
            base.OnPaint(pe);
        }
    }
```

It was not working, so I tried same in TabPage Paint event too, But both solution not working.

Comment: Use the Region property.

Comment: tried but not working

Comment: You did override the TabControl control ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working well... but not for `TabControl`. I don't know why.

As a workaround, I propose you to put your `TabControl` in an `UserControl` and move your code to the `UserControl`.

Comment: TabControl only lets you owner-draw the tabs.